# Fmask algorithm identifies buildings as Clouds for Sentinel-2

Tags: python, sentinel-2, cloudmasking

I am using the Fmask algorithm in order to mask clouds from my Sentinel-2 L1C images. I am doing this in python and I am following the documentation found on their website https://www.pythonfmask.org/en/latest/#introduction.
The code I am running:

```py
image_test = './S2B_MSIL1C_20201130T112429_N0209_R037_T29TNF_20201130T122309.SAFE'
out_image = 'clouds_mask.img'
sentinel2Stacked.mainRoutine(['--safedir',image_test,'-o',out_image])
```

Looking at the output the algorithm looks to be detecting well the clouds, where the first image is a rgb composite and the seconds one the output mask from Fmask (purple is cloud and yellow is shadow).

[image: rgb composite][image: fmask_output]

However when I go to areas with quite some buildings, it also identifies them as clouds/shadow.
[image: tgb composite buildings][image: fmask out]

I know this was a problem before as seen [here](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0034425718302037) , but supposedly the algorithm has been updated and this problem has gotten better.

Is this still a problem with Fmask or should I include more parameters when running the algorithm?

Comment: The f mask has a lot of pros but is not perfect and without the thermal band it is very hard to distinguish between the two. An alternative is to only use cloud free images but this reduces the number of images available to use...

Comment: This Fmask algorithm has several parameters that you can tweak. Generally, the defaults work but, I have found that occasionally you need to optimize the model. Without digging into old notes, I cannot recall what are relevant parameters but, there are a few key ones that can really change results. I would test on a small area with less idea results to see how results are being influenced. https://www.pythonfmask.org/en/latest/fmask_config.html